# Paragraph of text in a an equation

Tags: math-mode

It's kind of hard to describe my problem with words so let me start with a code sample :

```
 \documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
 \begin{document}

    \[
    \begin{array}{cccc}
    Y(N)_{\mathbf Z[\frac 1 N]} : & \mathbf Z[\frac 1 N]- Sch & \longrightarrow & Ens \\
                                  & T                         & \longmapsto       & \left\{ \begin{split}\text{Classes d'isomorphismes de paires $(E,\varphi)$ o\`u}\\ \text{ $E$ est une courbe elliptique sur $T$ et} \\ \text{ $\varphi : (\mathbf Z/N\mathbf Z)_T \to E[N]$ est}\\ \text{ un isomorphisme de sch\'emas en groupes sur $T$} \end{split}  \right \}
    \end{array}
    \]
    \end{document}
```

Basically i'm trying to fit a paragraph of text in an equation. I can do it using split but then I have to choose where to split itby hand + it looks very bad (cf above code). I would like a solution which splits everything nicely and automatically.

Comment: try setting a `\parbox` within `\text`.  then all you should have to do is decide how wide the `\parbox` is to be.  oh -- probably a good idea to set that text `\raggedright`.

Comment: Ah that's really exactly what I was looking for thank you very much !

Comment: Do you know it has been possible for more than twenty years  to typeset letters with accents *normally*? It suffices to add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} ` to your preamble.

Comment: @barbarabeeton No, a `\parbox` won't do, particularly if you set it `\raggedright`, unless you're particularly lucky that all lines are nearly full.

Comment: Yes I know about accents (although it might not look like i've actually type up a bit of latex). I just didn't want anyone to have problem with them so I used something that works with any encoding.

Comment: @egreg -- of course using `varwidth` is better, but why won't a `\parbox` work?  (and of course anything of the sort will look awful with wildly varying line lengths; `\raggedright` is usually the "least worst" alternative, and i see you've used it too.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton The closing brace will be as far from the opening brace as the width of the parbox, notwithstanding whether lines end short of it.

Comment: @egreg -- thanks.  well, i'm determined enough that if i were doing it, i'd just keep adjusting the width to look good with the longest line; that was kind of implied in my comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `varwidth` in order to have automatic line breaking and no excess spacing of the closing brace. Of course this assumes you really want to have a long textual description in the display, which I can't recommend.

Play with the relative width: the first has a very big pack of words, but at least the other symbols don't disappear with respect to it.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{array,varwidth}

\newcommand{\numberset}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\numberset{Z}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
Y(N)_{\Z[\frac{1}{N}]}\colon 
  \Z\Bigl[\frac{1}{N}\Bigr]\textup{-Sch} & \to \textup{Ens} \\
  T                                 & \mapsto
\left\{
  \begin{varwidth}{.4\displaywidth}
  \raggedright
  Classes d'isomorphismes de paires $(E,\varphi)$ o\`u $E$ est une courbe 
  elliptique sur $T$ et $\varphi\colon (\Z/N\Z)_T \to E[N]$ est un
  isomorphisme de sch\'emas en groupes sur $T$
  \end{varwidth}
\right \}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
Y(N)_{\Z[\frac{1}{N}]}\colon 
  \Z\Bigl[\frac{1}{N}\Bigr]\textup{-Sch} & \to \textup{Ens} \\
  T                                 & \mapsto
\left\{
  \begin{varwidth}{.5\displaywidth}
  \raggedright
  Classes d'isomorphismes de paires $(E,\varphi)$ o\`u $E$ est une courbe 
  elliptique sur $T$ et $\varphi\colon (\Z/N\Z)_T \to E[N]$ est un
  isomorphisme de sch\'emas en groupes sur $T$
  \end{varwidth}
\right \}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
Y(N)_{\Z[\frac{1}{N}]}\colon 
  \Z\Bigl[\frac{1}{N}\Bigr]\textup{-Sch} & \to \textup{Ens} \\
  T                                 & \mapsto
\left\{
  \begin{varwidth}{.6\displaywidth}
  \raggedright
  Classes d'isomorphismes de paires $(E,\varphi)$ o\`u $E$ est une courbe 
  elliptique sur $T$ et $\varphi\colon (\Z/N\Z)_T \to E[N]$ est un
  isomorphisme de sch\'emas en groupes sur $T$
  \end{varwidth}
\right \}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Centering the variable under the domain of the map is out of the question: it would appear to hang from nowhere. Also avoid `\longrightarrow` and `\longmapsto`: they are too long and add nothing other than occupying valuable space.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest you not to do that. Instead, use some name (convention) for the image of the morphism and then explain the meaning (I chose `Y(N)_{T}`, but change to the a name that suits you better):

```
 \documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
 \begin{document}

\begin{align*}
Y(N)_{\mathbf{Z}[\frac{1}{N}]} \colon 
  \mathbf Z\Bigl[\frac{1}{N}\Bigr]\textrm{-Sch} &\longrightarrow \textrm{Ens} 
\\
T &\longmapsto  Y(N)_{T},
\end{align*}
where $Y(N)_{T}$ is the set of classes d'isomorphismes de paires $(E,\varphi)$ o\`u $E$ est une courbe elliptique sur $T$ et $\varphi \colon (\mathbf Z/N\mathbf Z)_T \to E[N]$ est un isomorphisme de sch\'emas en groupes sur $T$.

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

I did some other modifications:

- To get the proper spacing for the colon when defining morphisms, you should use `\colon` instead of just `:`.
- I changed to an `align*` environment using the arrows as alignment points.
- I used `\textrm` for "Sch" and "Ens".

If you load `inputenc` with the appropriate encoding: `utf8` option, for example:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

you can enter French accents and special letters directly from the kwyboard.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. I think i'm gonna go with Barbar's suggestion above just because i'm kind of stuborn and I had my mind set on doing it this way. But I admit your solution is probably what would be best in the end. Thanks again.

Comment: @J.Doe This is what I'd do, personally.