# a stylish footnote: brackets for a whole paragraph of text

Tags: symbols, footnotes, csquotes

I'm looking to make **a stylish footnote**. I've came with the idea of putting *brackets to a whole paragraph* that comes at the end of the page. I've got a result but imagine it can be done better.

I've only managed to make a `mwe`, and to customize it line by line. But it still remains with the right border text lines not quite in order (left aligned instead of justified). 
If I wouldn't break lines the text would continue out of the page in only one "infinite" line.
Plus, the code is not very pretty as a result of my workaround.

Questions:

- Can this be done in another way to justify the text inside brackets?
- Is there other code possibilities for similar results?
- Are there other variants of this idea for footnotes?

I know there's a lot of questions about multiple line symbols in the site. However they are mostly in maths environments, and most likely not handling several lines of text. On the other hand, some questions on quotations could be useful, but I believe that the code should be simpler than these solutions: 

[Block quote with big quotation marks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16964/block-quote-with-big-quotation-marks?rq=1)
,
and 

[Block quote with big quotation marks and opening quote on bottom.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98984/block-quote-with-big-quotation-marks-and-opening-quote-on-bottom?rq=1)
 
Also, maybe there's a way to remake this mwe with `lipsum`, but since I was cutting lines I couldn't get around that.

Following is my **mwe**.

```
\documentclass[openany,11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{kpfonts,baskervald}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}

\begin{document}


\chapter*{Doña Lola}

\subsubsection*{Pears on red wine*}

ingredients: x, y and z.

Mix them and cook 'em.

\vfill

\begin{scriptsize}
\[ 
\left[ %\{
  \begin{tabular}{l}
* Tomado del libro \textit{el arte de la mesa}. Nota del editor:     Esta \\ 
receta también marida bien con variantes de helados cremosos. \\ 
Siguiendo la recomendación de la autora original, a la primera \\ 
preparación de las frutas le anexamos la otra receta de crema \\
que la acompaña.
  \end{tabular}
\right] 
\]
\end{scriptsize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get justified text quite simply. In fact an answer with modified `mwe` may come as a duplicate of 
[Paragraph of text in a an equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267716/paragraph-of-text-in-a-an-equation). However there are a reason or two to still try another answer separately.

The question remains open on how to use the `lipsum` package in a maths environment. This could simplify the mwe as requested to not work it out line by line. 
Also, there are not an excessive amount of posts on variants of how to make customized footnotes.

The rest of the modified `mwe` goes as follows.

```
\documentclass[openany,11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{kpfonts,baskervald}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{array,varwidth}
\newcommand{\numberset}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\numberset{Z}}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Doña Lola}

\subsubsection*{Pears on red wine*}

ingredients: x, y and z.

Mix them and cook em.

\vfill

\begin{align*}
\left[
  \begin{varwidth}{1\displaywidth} %\lipsum[1-4]
  * Tomado del libro \textit{el arte de la mesa}. Nota del editor: Esta receta también marida bien con variantes de helados cremosos. Siguiendo la recomendación de la autora original, a la primera preparación de las frutas le anexamos la otra receta de crema que la acompaña.
 \end{varwidth}
\right] 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Neither the question nor this answer actually use anything close to a footnote in the normal sense of the word, which makes it hard to understand what effect you are trying to achieve. If you want to put something at the bottom of a page manually, it is quite easy (as you have found), but automatic footnotes are much more complicated.

Comment: @jon ehm, actually you're mostly right, and I mean this code-sense. In the actual question, I was intending to make a proper footnote between brackets, it's just that I ended up with another solution. It would be nice to find a way to get this same result for all footnotes. This is why I believe the answer could be further developed: the question remains, _are there other code possibilities for similar results?_

Comment: I'm afraid you're asking for a major hack of the output routine, and I'm not convinced many people will agree that these brackets are 'stylish' enough to want to implement it (i.e., more trouble than payoff) without some added incentive. My TeX hacking skills are not sufficient, sadly.  Of course, the manual solution is easily done in a customizable via a package like `tcolorbox` ... but these would not be true footnotes.

Comment: @jon I agree. This is not stylish. In which ways could we find better solutions to hacking footnotes in different styles? Perhaps there is a thread somewhere on the topic?